# Create Glassfish windows service error

Tags: windows-services, glassfish

I have created glassfish service on window but could not start the service. I have checked the domain service error log and getting the following errors:

```
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required. 
could not find java.dll
Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

I have upgraded from Java 7 to Java 8 and after upgrading service could no be started. How can I solve this poroblem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok! I had to delete the following files: `java.exe`,  `javaw.exe` and `javaws.exe`

from System32 in order to work. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using any version of GlassFish below 4.1, it won't run on Java 8. You need to upgrade your GlassFish as well or, if that's not an option, revert to Java 7.